# CSS resize an image and keep the native ratio

Tags: html, css, image

What i'm trying to do here, is to crop an image to replace white spaces of my div:

```
<div id="profilepicture" style='background:url()'>
    <img src="utilisateurs/pp/<?php echo $userinfo['photoP']; ?>">
</div>
```

And here the stylesheet related to this:

```
#profilepicture{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
    display: flex;
}
#profilepicture img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Here is what it gives me :

[image: image1]

I just want to crop left and right of the photo and zoom at the center to not have white spaces anymore !

Edit:

If i do

```
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
```

it gives me this :

[image: image2]

Now i just want it to be centered!

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the image's height to 100% instead of the width?

Comment: In this example, if you set the height to 100%, the image will overflow out of the square parent container.  You would have to crop part of the image to the left and right.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Could you not use the image as backgorund image instead? That would be much easier to center.

Comment: I tried to do so but its a 2048x1369 picture so the div will crop the 200 pixels at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Clip

Use the `clip` property.

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 100px, 0);
}
```

One thing to note. clip only works on something `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. I don't know why. This limits its usefulness, but can be dealt with without too much trouble.

The second thing to note is about `rect()`. Its syntax (like many others in CSS) is `rect(top, right, bottom, left);`. Now pay attention here because it can be tricky. Both the top and the bottom values define the offset from the **top border** and the left and right values define the offset from the **left border**.

So `clip: rect(40px, 260px, 150px, 80px);` does the following.

[image]

---

### Using Background-Image

Probably the easiest option in terms of assembly.

```
<div id="profilepicture" style='background-image:url('utilisateurs/pp/<?php echo $userinfo['photoP']; ?>')'>
</div>

div {
  background-position: center;
}
```

This, more or less, does what you want, though it does have the side effect of using inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a background with "cover" property by moving the image to the background.

html:

```
<div id="profilepicture" style='background-image:url(utilisateurs/pp/<?php echo $userinfo['photoP']; ?>)'>
</div>
```

css:

```
#profilepicture{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
    display: flex;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

Set `overflow: hidden` on the parent container that contains the image.

You can then use absolute positioning to placed the left edge of the image to the center, and then use `translateX` to shift it to the left by 50% to center the image.

The net effect if to hide/crop the left and right edges of the image by hiding them (hide the overflow) in the parent container.

```css
#profilepicture {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#profilepicture img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="profilepicture">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Center it, add a negative margin and hide the overflow:

```css
#profilepicture{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
    display: flex;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#profilepicture img{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 -50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="profilepicture">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>
Here's what it looks like without the container:
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I hear you. I have just something very similar to this. There are a few ways to achieve this.

1. Use the not so well supported CSS property of `object-fit` - it does exactly what you want but you will need to use a [poyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit) if you want to support most browsers.
2. Set your image wrapper div to `overflow:hidden` as explained in this [guide](http://sixrevisions.com/css/circular-images-css/) The guide is for circular images, so just omit the `border-radius` parts.

If you prefer to see an example I have done one for both options. First option is the one that is commented out and the second option is the active one: http://codepen.io/cactusa/pen/qZrobK

Answer (score -1):

Reduce the height of the container (#profilepicture) because you have a square container with equal height and width but the img is a rectangle and doesn't have same height and width increasing the height of the img to 100% will cause distortion and look funny.

Comment: If i crop left and right i can center the picture but how can i do this in css